# Convert to NSDate from NSString: How to ignore the timezone

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, nsdate, iso8601

I am converting an NSString with a date format of `2012-06-30` into an NSDate using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

When omitting `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]]` the value in NSString is `2012-06-29 23:00:00` plus some automatically added time zone information, which indicates that the the system has some assumptions about the current time zone.

The conversion works fine when I set the time zone with the method above.

However, what would happen if the user is in a different time zone?

How can I make sure that iOS parses just the date as it is and does not add any time information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data will not change, timezones dont affect that date itself, it just affect the date presentation, so a date that says 13:00 GMT will have the same presentation of a date that is 14:00 GMT +1

You shouldnt care about the timezones, instead for date conversion to the current time zone of the device use

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

This will set the time zone of the device